# How do I send an e-mail through SMTP in iOS?

Tags: ios, smtp

I'm new to iPhone and iPad programming. How I can send an SMTP message without using the iPhone mail interface and the skpsmtp library? I tried a simple text message by using SMTP server name and user account, but this did not work.

Comment: What’s wrong with the SMTP library you mention?

Answer (score 2):

Without the native "iphone mail interface", as you call it, you will have to rely on third-party-libraries. There is no way to send an email without the native interface or third-party-libraries (without implementing an smtp-client all by yourself).

As SKPSMTPMessage is no-go for you, I can recommend [mailcore](http://libmailcore.com/), it's easy to set up and use. Used it once and worked like a charme. You can find the code on github containing examples [here](https://github.com/mronge/MailCore).